# Regex match text outside of brackets

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently using this regex but can figure out how to get the text group to combine its result.

```
String: Text 1^%+{TAB}({CMD 1}{CMD 2})Text 2.^(abc)

Regex: (?<special>[\^+%]*?[\(][^)]*[\)])|(?<special>[\^+%]*?[\{][^}]*[\}])|(?<text>.)

Result:
    text: T
    text: e
    text: x
    text: t
    text:  
    text: 1
    special: ^%+{TAB}
    special: ({CMD 1}{CMD 2})
    text: T
    text: e
    text: x
    text: t
    text:  
    text: 2
    special: ^(abc)

Wanted:
    text: Text 1
    special: ^%+{TAB}
    special: ({CMD 1}{CMD 2})
    text: Text 2
    special: ^(abc)
```

Ultimately I want "Text 1" and "Text 2" to be two groups in the text group. Can't seem to get the text group not to interfere with the special group when adding .*?(..) for the life of me.

Comment: Try [`(?<special>[+^%]*(?:\([^)]*\)|{[^}]*}))|(?<text>[\w\s]+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3cspecial%3e%5b%2b%5e%25%5d*%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5b%5e%29%5d*%5c%29%7c%7b%5b%5e%7d%5d*%7d%29%29%7c%28%3f%3ctext%3e%5b%5cw%5cs%5d%2b%29&i=Text+1%5e%25%2b%7bTAB%7d%28%7bCMD+1%7d%7bCMD+2%7d%29Text+2.%5e%28abc%29)

Comment: ^(Text 1).*(Text 2).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<special>[+^%]*(?:\([^)]*\)|{[^}]*}))|(?<text>[\w\s]+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Cspecial%3E%5B%2B%5E%25%5D*%28%3F%3A%5C%28%5B%5E%29%5D*%5C%29%7C%7B%5B%5E%7D%5D*%7D%29%29%7C%28%3F%3Ctext%3E%5B%5Cw%5Cs%5D%2B%29&i=Text%201%5E%25%2B%7BTAB%7D%28%7BCMD%201%7D%7BCMD%202%7D%29Text%202.%5E%28abc%29).

**Details**

- `(?<special>[+^%]*(?:\([^)]*\)|{[^}]*}))` - Group "special" capturing:

  - `[+^%]*` - zero or more `+`, `^` or `%` chars
  - `(?:` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) matching either of the two alternatives:

    - `\([^)]*\)` - a `(`, then 0+ chars other than `)` and then a `)`
    - `|` - or
    - `{[^}]*}` - a `{`, then 0+ chars other than `}` and then a `}`
  - `)`  - end of the non-capturing group.
- `|` - or
- `(?<text>[\w\s]+)`  - Group "text": one or more word or whitespace chars.

Comment: How would I match +^% without { or ( in the text group in this string?  `TEXT 1{SPECIAL 1}TEXT ^+% 2+^%(SPECIAL +^% 2)`

Comment: @Vnsax It is impossible to match discontinuous texts into one capturing group. You may replace all of those chars with an empty string, e.g. `match.Groups["special"].Value.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "")` or `Regex.Replace(match.Groups["special"].Value, @"[][{}]+", "")`

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string input = "Text 1^%+{TAB}({CMD 1}{CMD 2})Text 2.^(abc)";
            string pattern = @"^(?'text1'[^\^]+)(?'special1'[^\(]+)(?'special2'[^\)]+\))(?'text2'[^\^]+)(?'special3'.*)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
            Console.WriteLine("Text : '{0}' Special : '{1}' Special : '{2}' Text : '{3}' Special : '{4}'",
                match.Groups["text1"].Value,
                match.Groups["special1"].Value,
                match.Groups["special2"].Value,
                match.Groups["text2"].Value,
                match.Groups["special3"].Value
                    );
            Console.ReadLine();
```